# Combining 2 network inputs to an unmanaged switch to improve P2P and BitTorrent speed

Tags: networking, internet

I have two network inputs and I want to combine those for faster BitTorrent and P2P speed. Can I do it with an unmanaged network switch, and what software do I need?

My switch is TP-Link TL-SF1024D v2.

Comment: No you can’t use a switch to do this. It also depends on what you mean by “faster internet speed.” You can load balance the connections so that multiple downloads complete faster. But, one single download will always be limited by the fastest single internet connection you have. Your only other option is to bond the channels, which is done by the ISP. Anyways, the logistics behind this is more than can be answered in a single post. Do some research and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: What do you even mean by “two network inputs”? Do you have two jacks in the wall? Do you have two dedicated WAN connections each with its own router? Are you sure your WAN connections don’t share bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple links to the same network but not with single connections and not with consumer-grade hardware (edit: unless modded by DD-WRT or similar).

The best choice is to replace the switch with a gigabit model (assuming your Internet connection is above 100 Mbit/s and below 1 Gbit/s). If the Internet uplink is slower than 100 Mbit/s a faster switch accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely can be done with consumer grade hardware. Just not with consumer grade firmware on the device. You need to load third party, usually open source.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Agreed. DD-WRT and such add professional features to consumer-grade hardware. I was referring to the 'normal' state when the hardware is bought. ;-)

Comment: Gotcha, sorry to pick apart your post. But single connections, i.e residential Verizon or Comcast can also be aggregated/combined (not sure about other ISP's, VZ & Comcast are the only providers in my area.) This can even be done with wireless connections provided that they are on non-conflicting channels. I can give you more info if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, this can be done but not with the model router you have.

If you get a dd-wrt / oprnwrt router that is VLAN capable you can accomplish your goal. This can also be done with pfsense and a VLAN capable switch.

When you say "faster internet speed" I should clarify, BitTorrent/p2p = yes, web browsing=depends on the server. Your best bet to get faster speeds in this scenario is to divide the services being used, i.e send all web traffic/voip etc. out of connection one, send all p2p out both. Use qos on both connections if you divide the two.

Post a comment if you need clarification. Load balancing i.e sending one packet out of connection 1 and the next go's out of connection 2 doesn't work well because the far end server will drop connection #2 packets. I have had success with some sites not dropping packets. But Your mileage will vary.

Comment: I mean "faster Internet speed" is faster BitTorrent and P2P speed.

Comment: Yes, p2p can be easily aggregated from multiple connections using load balancing. Google dd-wrt load balancing, or pfsense gateway load balancing. Again, milage will vary trying to use this with http/https, you would have to make custom firewall rules to make sure specific protocols make it out of a designated gateway. Hope this helped!